# Get All simple product from a Configurable Product in Magento Product View

Tags: php, magento

How can I get all the simple products associated with a configurable product? I found how to do the opposite (get a product configurable from a simple product) but that's not what I need.

I want to show how many units I have in stock for the selected product (configurable attribute). My initial idea is to print all quantities of stock and control the display with jQuery. Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the following script in

> `app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`

Inside the script:

```
spConfig.getIdOfSelectedProduct = function () {
    var existingProducts = new Object();
    for (var i = this.settings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var selected = this.settings[i].options[this.settings[i].selectedIndex];
        if (selected.config) {
            for (var iproducts = 0; iproducts < selected.config.products.length; iproducts++) {
                var usedAsKey = selected.config.products[iproducts] + "";
                if (existingProducts[usedAsKey] == undefined) {
                    existingProducts[usedAsKey] = 1;
                } else {
                    existingProducts[usedAsKey] = existingProducts[usedAsKey] + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (var keyValue in existingProducts) {
        for (var keyValueInner in existingProducts) {
            if (Number(existingProducts[keyValueInner]) < Number(existingProducts[keyValue])) {
                delete existingProducts[keyValueInner];
            }
        }
    }
    var sizeOfExistingProducts = 0;
    var currentSimpleProductId = "";
    for (var keyValue in existingProducts) {
        currentSimpleProductId = keyValue;
        sizeOfExistingProducts = sizeOfExistingProducts + 1
    }
    if (sizeOfExistingProducts == 1) {
        alert("Selected product is: " + currentSimpleProductId)
    }
}
```

Now add `onchange` event to your dropdown in same page :

```
onchange = "spConfig.getIdOfSelectedProduct()"
```

[Full description](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.com/2012/09/getting-selected-simple-product-id-in.html)

Comment: Awesome solution Hardik!

Comment: This isn't PHP though.

Comment: @Qix, it's Javascript. Since it needs to be executed client-side, when the customer selects an option from a drop-down, PHP would be useless (unless accompanied by some AJAX-powered Javascript).

Answer (score 58):

Use this below code

Code to get the the full product information  (where 3 is the configurable product Id)

```php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3); 
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getUsedProducts(null,$product);

foreach($childProducts as $child) {
    print_r($child->getName());  // You can use any of the magic get functions on this object to get the value
}
```

Another code to get the Children Product Ids

```php
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getChildrenIds(3);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getChildrenIds() on a non-object

Comment: `$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds(3);` worked perfectly for me (minus the extra semi-colon.  Thanks!

Comment: The first method gives me all the child products, but it says all the child products are enabled, even though most are actually disabled. Why is that?

Comment: @NickRolando use better the 2nd option. This one works perfect!

Answer (score 18):

A configurable product can have multiple other products associated to it.

Here is the code to fetch all the children products that are associated with a configurable product.

Here goes the code :)

```
/**
 * Load product by product id
 */
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(YOUR_PRODUCT_ID);

/**
 * Get child products id and such (only ids)
 */
$childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());

/**
 * Get children products (all associated children products data)
 */
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);
```

Source: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-all-associated-children-product-of-a-configurable-product/

Comment: Note that you can simply do this instead of loading the `product_type_configurable` model manually: `$product->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds()` or `$product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts()`.

Answer (score 5):

I got it. Thanks for the replies.

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"): ?>
    <?php $_configurable = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds(); ?>
    <?php foreach ($_configurable as $_config): ?>
        <?php $_simpleproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_config); ?>
        <?php //Magic php with a $_simpleproduct. ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: you shouldn't `load()` inside a loop

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking to do this, and display the results I will share what I did to finish it off

Add to the `script` segment of: **app/design/frontend/default/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml**

```
id = {};
<?php 
foreach ($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $_product) as $simple) {
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simple)->getQty();
    echo "  id[" . $simple->getId() . "] = $stock;\n\r";
}
?>

    spConfig.getIdOfSelectedProduct = function () {
        var existingProducts = new Object();
        for (var i = this.settings.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var selected = this.settings[i].options[this.settings[i].selectedIndex];
            if (selected.config) {
                for (var iproducts = 0; iproducts < selected.config.products.length; iproducts++) {
                    var usedAsKey = selected.config.products[iproducts] + "";
                    if (existingProducts[usedAsKey] == undefined) {
                        existingProducts[usedAsKey] = 1;
                    } else {
                        existingProducts[usedAsKey] = existingProducts[usedAsKey] + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (var keyValue in existingProducts) {
            for (var keyValueInner in existingProducts) {
                if (Number(existingProducts[keyValueInner]) < Number(existingProducts[keyValue])) {
                    delete existingProducts[keyValueInner];
                }
            }
        }
        var sizeOfExistingProducts = 0;
        var currentSimpleProductId = "";
        for (var keyValue in existingProducts) {
            currentSimpleProductId = keyValue;
            sizeOfExistingProducts = sizeOfExistingProducts + 1
        }
        if (sizeOfExistingProducts == 1) {
           var qtyLeft = id[currentSimpleProductId];
           if(qtyLeft >= 1) {
               jQuery('.availability-only').html('Only ' + qtyLeft + ' available.');
               jQuery('p.out-of-stock').removeClass('out-of-stock').addClass('in-stock');
               jQuery('p.in-stock > span').html('In stock');
           } else {
               jQuery('.availability-only').html('Sorry, there are none available in this size.');
               jQuery('p.in-stock').removeClass('in-stock').addClass('out-of-stock');
               jQuery('p.out-of-stock > span').html('Out of stock');
           }
        }
    }
```

in the `select` of the same page add:

```
 onchange = "spConfig.getIdOfSelectedProduct()"
```

Feel free to edit what the statement prints, but this should get you there.  It also accounts for 0 stock on hand, changing it to `Out of stock` in css and text

Answer (score 0):

write the below simplest code in block and just call it in your template file to get the products associated products :

```
    $productId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\objectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product")->load($productId);
    $collection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProducts($product);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
```

now, in template write the below code to print the names :

```
   $collection = $block->getCollection(); 
   foreach ($collection as $key => $value) 
   {
      echo $value->getName();
      echo "<br>";
   }
```